# How to use scroll.js on jQuery generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to use [scroll.js](https://github.com/hakimel/stroll.js/blob/master/README.md) on my website. The basic usage is:

```
<ul id="mylist">
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
</ul>
```

And then with javascript (raw or jQuery) I can target that list with `stroll.bind('#mylist');` and in turn the list gets the required animation.

What I really want to do is add list items into `.mylist` dynamically and then be able to apply `stroll.bind('#mylist');`. I tried everything, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    more = $(".moretitles");
    wrap = $(".mylist li#index");
more.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    item = $(".one").clone();
    item.appendTo($(".mylist" ));
})
stroll.bind( $('.mylist' ) );
});
```

I know that the code above is messy but just to give you the idea that I'm adding to the list. As I said these new list items are not effected by `stroll.bind( $('.mylist' ) );`. Is there a way to add the `stroll` effect to the dynamic content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather use:

```
more.on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
item = $(".one").clone();
item.appendTo($(".mylist" ));
stroll.bind( $('.mylist' ) );//bind event on change of contents.
})
```